# Symplectic structures on the total space of vector bundles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, vector-bundles

> What is  a smooth two dimensional  real  vector  bundle $E$ over $S^{2}$ such that the total  space  $E$, as  a  smooth  four  manifold,  does  not admit a symplectic structure?

To what extent  all even dimensional  smooth  bundles over $S^{2}$ with a symplectic structure are  classified? Assume that $E,F$ are two such vector  bundles.  Does $E\oplus F$ or  $E\otimes F$  admit  a symplectic structure, too?

The question is  motivated by existence of  a symplectic structure on the the cotangent bundle of manifolds.

Comment: Every real rank 2 vector bundle over the 2-sphere admits a complex structure, and is an algebraic line bundle over the complex projective line, so is a quasiprojective variety and admits a symplectic structure.

Comment: @BenMcKay  Thanks a lot. Is there  a  proof without  algebraic  geometry?Can you give  an elementary  reference about the algebraic geometric  aspect  of  your  comment? Do you think that it would  be obvious to ask :"Is there a symplectic structure such that each fibre is  a Lagrangian submanifold?